# How to enable gzip compression on production build in angular 12?

Tags: javascript, angular

1.Integrated new web.config.js for gzip compression, https://i.stack.imgur.com/MuVt4.png

2.Updated angular.json file,

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "./webpack.config.js"
            },
```

dist files are compressed with .gz extention and but it is not reflecting on browser after deployment.

3.'content-encoding:gzip' is not showing on browser network response header, https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkSoV.png.

is there anything to handle on server side for enabling this?

Comment: Gzip should be enabled by configuring the webserver that hosts the files (Apache, iis, nginx, ...)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using web servers like apache / nginx you can enable gz compression on your web server